# Enabling active FTP mode in IIS on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp, passive

I am trying to connect to my IIS website using Dreamweaver.

When I use the `Use passive FTP` option, I am able to connect. However, unchecking this option results in a timeout and error.

So far everything is alright.

Now I want to use another client (the FTP explorer plugin on the Eclipse IDE) but it doesn't connect. I am using the same address and same credentials.

After looking at the settings, it turns out that the plugin does not have a passive FTP option. Can I enable the active FTP mode on the server as a workaround? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Active vs/passive is usually set on the client.  Is there a NAT between the client and server?  Passive ftp works better through some firewalls.  Have you tried temporarily disabling any host-based firewalls to be sure it isn't a firewall issue?

Comment: There seems to be a passive mode checkbox in this screenshot.  http://www.boyzoid.com/images/ftp_eclipse/step2.jpg  Am I looking at the wrong [guide](http://www.boyzoid.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/3/21/Using-FTP-from-inside-CFEclipse)?

Answer (score 2):

IIS supports both Active and Passive FTP connections by default. You don't have to do anything special to enable either one. You also can't disable either one as far as I know. You can however, configure the port range that IIS will use for Passive FTP sessions, but that won't help you here. The problem is most likely that your firewall doesn't support or isn't configured to allow Active mode FTP sessions, so your options are to find and enable the Passive mode FTP settings in your application or configure your firewall to allow Active mode FTP sessions.